# RxSwift: BheaviorRelay exclude default value

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I am new to RxSwift. How can I exclude default value for BehaviorRelay.
My code:

```
  idObservable.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] id in
        self?.fetchData(id)
  }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use skip function for this:

```
idObservable.skip(1).subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] id in
        self?.fetchData(id)
  }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```